# Keep preview on landscape

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm creating my first report in ssrs and it should be printed in landscape.

Right-clicking the preview and selecting `Page Setup` allows me to set the page orientation. Whenever I change **anything** on the layout page, the page properties revert to portrait.

Any idea how to make my *layout -> check preview -> layout* development cycle a bit more pleasant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself :S

In 2005:

- Select Layout tab
- Choose Report => Report Properties => Layout
- Set dimensions to [choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size)

In 2008 (not personally tested)

- Report Menu => Report Properties => landscape or portrait